# Celery worker Queues

Tags: python, celery

I currently using "Celeryd" to run my Celery workers as a daemon. My /etc/default/celeryd file contains the following:

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"
```

Which obviously starts three worker processes.

How do I configure routing to work with this configuration? e.g.

```
celeryd -c 2 -l INFO -Q import
```

If I run celery from the command line I can specify the queue using the -Q flag. I need to tell my w1 worker process to only process tasks from the "import" queue.

Answer (score 7):

You can make different workers consume from different/same queues by giving proper args in CELERYD_OPTS.

Refer this: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html

The link is for celery multi documentation, but you can give the argument in same way to your case also.

```
# Advanced example starting 10 workers in the background:
#   * Three of the workers processes the images and video queue
#   * Two of the workers processes the data queue with loglevel DEBUG
#   * the rest processes the default' queue.
$ celery multi start 10 -l INFO -Q:1-3 images,video -Q:4,5 data -Q default -L:4,5 DEBUG
```

can be used as:

```
$ CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8 -l INFO -Q:1-3 images,video -Q:4,5 data -Q default -L:4,5 DEBUG"
```

Do not create extra daemons unless required.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directive named `CELERYD_OPTS` to add optional command line arguments.

```
# Names of nodes to start
#   most will only start one node:
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=4 -Q import"
```

But as far as I know this option will tell all the workers will consume from only the import queue.

If you cannot find an acceptable answer, you may try to run workers separately.

Comment: Arr OK - Thats what I thought. Is it possible to run workers separately as daemons?

Comment: yes you can have multiple workers. http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html just create celeryd init script for each worker; like ```/etc/init.d/worker1d```, ```/etc/init.d/worker2d``` and create configuration files with the same name ```/etc/default/worker1d```, ```/etc/default/worker2d```. As it is obvious, now you can configure any worker independently.

Comment: if using names nodes like above it seems one cannot use `-Q:1-3 name` but should name them like `-Q:w1,w2,w3 name`

Answer (score -1):

It's worth noting that you can use node names with the CELERYD_OPTS arguments, for example

```
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=4 --concurrency:w3=8 -Q:w1 import"
```